# Adding data from the xml into a SQL Server database in Biztalk

Tags: sql-server, xslt, biztalk

I have a XML in the format below with fields company and account etc, which would be the source schema

```
<Root xmlns="http://schema.Balance_SourceSchema">
    <Balance xmlns="">
        <Company>"PKG"</Company>
        <Account>"1010.10.10"</Account>
        <Type>"P&L"</Type>
        <Description>"FREIGHT REVENUE"</Description>
        <Units>""</Units>
        <Branch>"HKC"</Branch>
        <Department>"BIL"</Department>
        <Activity>"Forwarding"</Activity>
        <Direction>"Export"</Direction>
        <Mode>"Sea"</Mode>
        <Year>"2023"</Year>
        <Period>"202305"</Period>
        <AmountInPeriod>"-31,844.20</AmountInPeriod>
        <Currency>"HAKD"</Currency>
    </Balance> ...
```

And the table should have the same fields + ID, Created Date added to it.

Comment: It is possible to call SQL Server stored procedure and pass XML in its entirety as a parameter of XML data type. That stored procedure will shred the XML parameter, and insert data into  a target table.

Comment: ok, I have created a source and destination schema and direct mapped it and created a send port of WCF_SQL type with database name in the Url and in Action I have added the path to the store proc. Now I have to write the store proc and would that fill the xml data to the table.

Comment: You can edit your question, and add target table structure, as well as XML parameter sample. And I will give you a hand.

Comment: Sure thanks, I have made the edit

Comment: Have you just tried to use the WCF-SQL adapter and select a table insert operation, and it would generate the appropriate schema for SQL, which you can then map the data from your schema to.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following as a starting point for your stored procedure.

You may need to adjust a couple of things:

- Modify `.value()` method 2nd parameter data types to match your target table.
- Remove surrounding double quotes via `TRIM()` function.

**SQL**

```sql
DECLARE @param XML = 
N'<Root xmlns="http://schema.Balance_SourceSchema">
    <Balance xmlns="">
        <Company>"PKG"</Company>
        <Account>"1010.10.10"</Account>
        <Type>"P&amp;L"</Type>
        <Description>"FREIGHT REVENUE"</Description>
        <Units>""</Units>
        <Branch>"HKC"</Branch>
        <Department>"BIL"</Department>
        <Activity>"Forwarding"</Activity>
        <Direction>"Export"</Direction>
        <Mode>"Sea"</Mode>
        <Year>"2023"</Year>
        <Period>"202305"</Period>
        <AmountInPeriod>"-31,844.20</AmountInPeriod>
        <Currency>"HAKD"</Currency>
    </Balance>
</Root>';
    
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schema.Balance_SourceSchema' AS ns1)
--INSERT INTO <targetTable> (Company, Account, ...)
SELECT TRIM('"' FROM c.value('(Company/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')) AS Company
, c.value('(Account/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Account
, c.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Type
, c.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Description
, c.value('(Units/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Units
, c.value('(Branch/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Branch
, c.value('(Department/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Department
, c.value('(Activity/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Activity
, c.value('(Direction/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Direction
, c.value('(Mode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Mode
, c.value('(Year/text())[1]', 'CHAR(4)') AS Year
, c.value('(Period/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS Period
, c.value('(AmountInPeriod/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS AmountInPeriod
, c.value('(Currency/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Currency
FROM @param.nodes('/ns1:Root/Balance') AS t(c);
```

Comment: But what if there are multiple table data that need to be inserted, inserting so many is it feasible

Comment: It will work without any problem to insert multiple *balance* rows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by creating a consume adapter service which would be the destination schema and use the map in the orchestration and use a req, resp port and that gave me the table printed with the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).